# Why is text content affecting table cell width?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table like:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="header" colspan="2">
          <h1>
            Thisismytitlexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          </h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sidebar"></td>
      <td class="main">
          <div class="bubble">lorem1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want `#sidebar td` to be 8px wide until content is added to it, whereupon it should expand to fit content.

In Safari 8.0.3 the width is performing strangely - text content in the `<h1>` is affecting the size of `#sidebar` (the first `td` in the next `tr`); adding characters makes it bigger, adding spaces makes it smaller. The width changes if the text in `.bubble` is altered too.

code demo:
http://jsbin.com/cucacekapu/edit?html,css,output

Setting a pixel width on `td.main` solves the issue, but why is this happening and is there a way to fix it without setting a pixel width?

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout: fixed`  to the CSS rules for your table.